# Parsing number out of a string in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using an API that brings back more information than I need in the field.

Currently, {{row['gametime']['text']}} brings back:

```
Tennessee Titans at Jacksonville Jaguars - 8:25 pm Game Preview
```

In my list, I just need it to display as:

```
8:25
```

Here's the Angular ng-repeater:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="row in data">

        <span class="gametime">{{row['gametime']['text']}}</span>
      </ion-item>
```

I want to modify that {{row['gametime']['text']}} text so it only displays the number. Is there a way in Angular (or JS/jQuery) to parse out the number that comes back in the string?

Comment: you will have to use native js string methods to do it either in a filter or mapping the data a bit when you receive it

Comment: How would I go about doing a filter?

Comment: Start by reading the filter docs. Can also use a controller function in your markup to do it

Comment: In your case I would write some bindonce directive or generate new list on service side instead to work in HTML. It will make code readable and easy to understand + debug. Also don't forget that regex might be expensive if you have big list and don't remove watchers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ng-filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

JS:

```
myApp.filter('getTime', function() {
  return function (data) {

// find in string data.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/ two numbers, and get it 
// (data.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/) || [])[0] this line similar to this code but more shorter 
// var time = data.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/
// if (time && Array.isArray(time)) {
//    return time[0];
// }

      return typeof data === 'string' ? (data.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/) || [])[0]  : data;
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="gametime">{{row['gametime']['text'] | getTime}}</span>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9386/